# How to raise the javascript function (that is presented in master page) from iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how i raise the javascript function (that is presented in master page)
from iframe
in iframe i have displaying a aspx page
i want to call from code behind of iframe page

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "Alert", "Show_NotifyDiv();", True)

Answer (score 2):

**Following is an example using javascript.**

master page/page of the iframe:

```
function fnMaster(para1){
   alert(para1);
)
```

page within iframe:

```
function callMasterFunction(){
   parent.fnMaster("Hello master");
}
```